# .setText() for different layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to use `.setText()` for a different layout other than `.setContentView(layout)`.

I have listview(main.xml) which include buttons so I have made another xml(button.xml) for it. Now if I want to set text through programming in main.xml then `.setText()` works normally but in case of button.xml then `.setText()` shows **java error and crashes my app**.

I am doing it like this

 MainActivity

```
 String username = "hello";
 TextView user_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
 user_name.setText("Name : " + username);
```

button.xml

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            />
```

error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can anybody have any idea about how to do that.

Comment: just added my code.

Comment: yes are inflating this textview?

Comment: @Atula you need to use instance of Textview to apply setText()

Comment: I have already done that

Comment: @Atula can you show us?

Comment: What are the Java errors please? At a glance this looks correct

Comment: have a check on my code @Nisarg

Comment: @Atula android:layout-_height="wrap_content" did you check this? or it just a typo?

Comment: oh it is just a typo error . I'll correct that

Comment: is there any kind of condition that *.stText()*  will only work on the layout set in  *.setContentView(layout)*.

Comment: @Atula code looks perfect check .setContentView(R.layout.button) once if it causes problem

Comment: you need to inflate the layout if you want to use the custom xml layout ..

Comment: i didn't get it why should i check for a button layout

Comment: please provide your whole code

Comment: I have provided the tutorial link in the comments of the answer. please find that @MohammedSameerAhmad

Comment: please provide whole code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have followed your question- are you trying to attach a child view to the Layout? If so you want to do something along the lines of:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_parent_view);// in main activity
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button, null);
parent.addView(child);


 String username = "hello";
 TextView user_name = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
 user_name.setText("Name : " + username);
```

Comment: and where i am suppose to add this . In MainActivity or the Child one ?

Comment: i think providing this tutorial would be better http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/. here in this, I need to setText() for myList.xml textview

Comment: So you are following this tutorial ? and what is the use of buttons here ?? .. its simple TextView...

Comment: just playing around with different views. So have you got any idea?

Comment: is your code is in adapter class?? Actually show your code.. what you are running..

Comment: It is ListActivity. well leave it i'll try to find something on my own.